# How can I find the difference between two columns with times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this:

```
VendorID lpep_pickup_datetime lpep_dropoff_datetime store_and_fwd_flag  \
0         2  2017-03-01 00:30:18   2017-03-01 00:30:47                  N   
1         2  2017-03-01 00:11:58   2017-03-01 01:05:54                  N   
2         2  2017-03-01 00:54:44   2017-03-01 01:03:42                  N   
3         2  2017-03-01 00:00:07   2017-03-01 00:04:39                  N   
4         2  2017-03-01 00:17:05   2017-03-01 00:36:44                  N
```

I tried this:

```
data['trip_duration'] = data['lpep_dropoff_datetime'] - data['lpep_pickup_datetime']
data['trip_duration'] = data['trip_duration']/np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

I also tried this:

```
data['trip_duration'] = data['lpep_dropoff_datetime'].values - data['lpep_pickup_datetime'].values
data['trip_duration'] = data['trip_duration']/np.timedelta64(1,'m')
```

In both cases, I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I'm trying to create a new column named 'trip_duration' which shows the difference in times.  Finally, if the start and end dates were different, like before and after midnight, I'd like the code to handle that seamlessly.

Comment: Have you tried to use datetime module ? 
datetime.datetime.strptime(data['lpep_dropoff_datetime'] , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how the `'2017-03-01 00:30:18'` ascii timestamp value got into your dataframe.
If you populated it with [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and there weren't any extraneous (non-date) values, then pandas should have parsed the dates for you.
You can use this to post-process:

```
import datetime as dt

def str_to_stamp(s):
    return dt.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

data['lpep_dropoff_datetime'] = data['lpep_dropoff_datetime'].apply(str_to_stamp)
data['lpep_pickup_datetime'] = data['lpep_pickup_datetime'].apply(str_to_stamp)
```

String subtraction doesn't work very well,
but subtracting timestamps will give you time deltas.

Comment: That works!  Thanks.  So, it's basically converting the data type from object to datetime64[ns], right.